# Why do year and month functions result in long overflow in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I'm trying to make year and month columns from a column named logtimestamp (of type TimeStampType) in spark. The data source is cassandra. I am using sparkshell to perform these steps, here is the code I have written -

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
var logsDF = spark.read.cassandraFormat("tableName", "cw").load()
var newlogs = logsDF.withColumn("year", year(col("logtimestamp")))
 .withColumn("month", month(col("logtimestamp")))
newlogs.write.cassandraFormat("tableName_v2", "cw")
 .mode("Append").save()
```

But these steps do not succeed, I end up with the following error

```
java.lang.ArithmeticException: long overflow
    at java.lang.Math.multiplyExact(Math.java:892)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.millisToMicros(DateTimeUtils.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.util.DateTimeUtils$.fromJavaTimestamp(DateTimeUtils.scala:166)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$TimestampConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$TimestampConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:242)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:107)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$.$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:426)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.UnsafeRowReader.read(UnsafeRowReaderFactory.scala:34)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.UnsafeRowReader.read(UnsafeRowReaderFactory.scala:21)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraPartitionReaderBase.$anonfun$getIterator$2(CassandraScanPartitionReaderFactory.scala:110)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.next(Iterator.scala:459)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:494)
    at com.datastax.spark.connector.datasource.CassandraPartitionReaderBase.next(CassandraScanPartitionReaderFactory.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.PartitionIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.MetricsIterator.hasNext(DataSourceRDD.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$10.hasNext(Iterator.scala:458)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:755)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.$anonfun$run$1(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:413)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.DataWritingSparkTask$.run(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:452)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.v2.V2TableWriteExec.$anonfun$writeWithV2$2(WriteToDataSourceV2Exec.scala:360)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:497)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1439)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:500)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I thought it was something to do with null values in the table so I ran the following

```
scala> logsDF.filter("logtimestamp is null").show()
```

But this too gave the same long overflow error.

How come there is an overflow in spark but not in cassandra when both have timestamps of 8 bytes?
What could be the issue here and how do I extract year and month from timestamp correctly?

Comment: Could you share an example of values from `logtimestamp` column?

Comment: @Gabip Yes, here are some examples of logtimestamp (as they are shown in spark) - 2021-03-04 10:29:59.311, 2021-03-04 10:29:59.014, 2021-05-03 21:29:56.699. Their type is TimestampType according to logsDF.dtypes

Comment: Could https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-35679 be related?

Comment: @mazaneicha Oh could this be the issue? But I'm using spark 3.1.2 with scala 2.12.10. The link doesn't mention anything about 3.1.2

Comment: It mentions the issue is fixed in 3.1.3

Comment: @mazaneicha Upgraded to 3.2.0 but the issue still persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out one of the cassandra table had a timestamp value that was greater than the highest value allowed by spark but not large enough to overflow in cassandra. The timestamp had been manually edited to get around the upserting that is done by default in cassandra, but this led to some large values being formed during development.
Ran a python script to find this out.

Comment: Nice find! Can you add a sample value that was causing this?

Comment: @mazaneicha Unfortunately I deleted those rows. It was just a very large number. While Cassandra showed other proper timestamps in yyyy-MM-hh... format, it showed the number as it is.

Comment: Aaahhh niceties of schema-on-read?

Comment: @mazaneicha Yes, I think that is what it was. Tried a lot to disable it for the cassandra connector and use BigInt for timestamp while debugging, but was unsuccessful.